# Dynamic Reload Function Based on Width

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I am trying to make my slider picking dynamically changed width of the window and put the right variable "newscount" to "slidesPerSlide : window.newscount" plus reload the last part:

```
swiperLoop = $('.swiper-loop').swiper({
    slidesPerSlide : window.newscount,
    loop:false
});
```

Please help me, the code is below:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w < 321) {
            var newscount = "2";
        }
        else if (w < 480) {
            var newscount = "3";
        }
        else if (w < 640) {
            var newscount = "5";
        }
        else if (w < 720) {
            var newscount = "8";
        }
        else if (w > 721) {
            var newscount = "8";
        }
    }); 

    swiperLoop = $('.swiper-loop').swiper({
        slidesPerSlide : window.newscount,
        loop:false
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to initialize your swiper based on the window size and then update the `slidesPerSlide` param on the `window.resize` event:

```
$(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();

    var swiperLoop = $('.swiper-loop').swiper({
        slidesPerSlide: getSlideCount(width),
        loop: false
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        width = $(window).width();
        swiperLoop.params.slidesPerSlide = getSlideCount(width);
    }); 
});

function getSlideCount(windowSize) {
    if (windowSize < 321) {
        return 2;
    } else if (windowSize < 480) {
        return 3;
    } else if (windowSize < 640) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return 8;
    }
}
```

Also, it's best to stay away from adding global variables to the `window` object. This can cause conflicts or unexpected behavior in other libraries.

Comment: Thanks CFS. Is it possible to detect the loaded window first and put variable, and after check the resizing and refresh whole function?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to know if you can store the window size in a variable? Yes you can, though you will need to update the value of that variable every time the window is resized. You can then pass that variable to the `getSlideCount` function.

Comment: Also, I just noticed a typo in my original answer: I was updating the  `loop` property when I should have been updating the `slidesPerSlide` property. I updated my answer so that it should be correct. I also stored the window size in a variable in response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you cfs. I still got no luck. The slider I am trying to make working is here: http://jsfiddle.net/v8gLu/1/

Maybe it will be useful to have a look if you have got a spare second.

Comment: I have got an error which says - Uncaught ReferenceError: mySwiper is not defined

Comment: @qqruza Ah... sorry I had a typo in the resize handler, try it now

Comment: That's a great solution! You are a super developer cfs!

Answer (score 0):

$(window).on('load', function(){

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var w = $(window).width();

    this.newscount="0";

    if (w < 321) {
        this.newscount="1";
    }
    else if (w < 480) {
       this.newscount="2";
    }
    else if (w < 640) {
      this.newscount="3";
    }
    else if (w < 720) {
       this.newscount="4";
    }
    else if (w > 721) {
        this.newscount="5";
    }
}); 

swiperLoop = $('.swiper-loop').swiper({
    slidesPerSlide : this.newscount,
    loop:false
});
```

});